# Debug Java Application in Nuix - Attach a Profiler or Debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jvm, jvm-hotspot

My goal is to attach a Java profiler or debugger to an instance of the Java Virtual Machine started by a Windows application called [Nuix](https://www.nuix.com/).

It is possible to pass command line switches to Nuix, some of which it passes to the JVM.

Nuix is packaged with JRE 8 in one of its subdirectories: `\Nuix 7.4\jre\`. It appears that the particular version is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_92.

I launched Nuix with these switches:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=80
```

I then tried running `jconsole.exe` without command line switches, and it did not recognize the JVM started by Nuix. I tried creating a remote connection using `jdb.exe -attach <Port>`, but the application failed with this exception.

```
java.io.IOException: shmemBase_attach failed: The system cannot find the file specified
```

I verified that nothing else is listening on port 80 and it is not blocked.

What the proper way to attach a debugger?

As a side question, how is it possible for a Windows .exe to use JARs? I have not seen this architecture before, and I do not believe IKVM.NET is used, and J# is not used because the application is unmanaged, according to Process Explorer.

Comment: `As a side question, how is it possible for a Windows .exe to use JARs?` In exactly the same way as a shell script can. Since the entire Java VM is included in the distribution, you can just start it as a separate process.

Comment: Using Process Monitor, I believe that \jre\bin\java.dll is responsible for loading the JARs. Is that a known method for making JARs accessible to a Windows application? @biziclop

Comment: The .exe is a wrapper which calls JNI_CreateJavaVM to start up the JVM. It also loads some memory preferences from the registry to pass to the JVM (i.e. via -Xmx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To attach a debugger, I did the following. Note that I used port 80 due to a firewall configuration that I cannot alter. I realize that port 8000 is the conventional Java debug port.

**jconsole.exe**

1. Start Nuix with this switch.

   ```
   -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=80
   ```
2. Get the Windows process ID of nuix_app.exe.
3. Run `jconsole.exe <PID>`.

**jdb.exe**

1. Start Nuix with this switch.

   ```
   -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=80
   ```
2. Run jdb.exe with these switches:

   ```
   jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:port=80
   ```
3. Type `run` to take Nuix out of suspend mode.

**Eclipse Mars**

1. Start Nuix with this switch.

   ```
   -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=80
   ```
2. Go to Run -> Debug Configurations... -> Remote Java Application.
3. Configure

   ```
   Connection Type = Standard (Socket Attach)
   Host = localhost
   Port = 80
   ```
4. Click `Debug`.
5. Go to Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Java.

**Java Mission Control (jmc.exe)**

1. Start Nuix with these switches

   ```
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=80
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
   ```
2. Click Create a new custom JVM Connection.
3. Configure options

   ```
   Host = 127.0.0.1
   Port = 80
   ```
4. Click the Test Connection button.

**VisualVM 1.4**

1. Start Nuix with these switches

   ```
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=80
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
   ```
2. In the Applications tree, right-click Local, and then click Add JMX Connection....
3. Set the connection to `localhost:80`, and Click OK.
4. In the Applications tree, double-click localhost:80 (pid: [process ID])

---

### Running the JVM from a Windows Process

Based on the presence of JavaAccessBridge-64.dll, I believe that Nuix uses [Java Access Bridge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/introduction.htm).